# makefile fails - implicit rule compiles one object file but doesn't compile the rest

Tags: makefile

Makefile isn't using implicit rules correctly. I am following this guide [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/make-doc/make.html/Introduction.html#Introduction).

Here's my makefile:

```
objects = main.o hello.o
hello : $(objects)
    cc -o hello $(objects)

hello.o : defs.h
main.o : defs.h hello.h

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm hello $(objects)
```

I get the following error:

```
cc: error: main.o: No such file or directory
```

It creates the object code hello.o, but does not do it for main.c. If I swap lines and main is above, it'll create main.o but not hello.o.

Here's my main.c file:

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "hello.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   display_hello();
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here's my hello.c file:

```
#include "defs.h"

void display_hello()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

My hello.h file:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* HELLO_H */

void display_hello();
```

Here's my defs.h file:

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* DEFS_H */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`.)

Comment: It's GNU Make 4.1. Trying out Autotools now, it seems much easier to uses.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, I created the files as https://gist.github.com/boyvinall/f23420215707fa3e73e21c3f9a5ff22b

```
$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
cc -o hello main.o hello.o
```

Might be the version of `make` like @Beta said, but even an old version of GNU make should work just fine for this.

Otherwise, ensure you're using tabs to indent in the makefile, not spaces.